# I have no choice but verb(to / -ing or none)

Tags: american-english, infinitive-vs-gerund

Which one is correct?

1. > I have no choice but to kill you.
2. > I have no choice but killing you.
3. > I have no choice but kill you.

or do they have different meanings?

Comment: @IͶΔ why true is 'incorrect' :)

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95548/true-vs-right-vs-correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*But* in these examples functions as a preposition meaning *except*. It is sometimes followed by a verb.The form depends on what came before. Infinitives are usually without *to*, but sometimes we need a gerund.

> She does nothing but sleep all day.
>
> He doesn't like anything but playing on his computer. (like ... playing)

Infinitives with *to* are used after *no choice, option, alternative but*

> I have no choice but to kill.(This sentence is correct).

Answer (score 1):

So your question is -

> ...no choice but [?]

What can take the place of [?]. That is what you are asking, right?

Well, **but** there is a preposition, meaning *except*, and it can license either a **matrix-licensed-complement** or a **Noun Phrase** [NP].

> 1.(a) There’s been nothing but trouble since he came. [License NP] 
>   1.(b) Black people used to have no choice but field work because there were few other opportunities to earn money. [License NP]
>
> 2.(a) We had no choice but to believe them. [Matrix clause - *We had (to believe them)*] 
>   2.(b) He had no choice but to ​leave. [Matrix clause - *He had (to leave)*]

So if it can license a NP, there is no reason for it to license **Gerund-Participle**. So grammatically the following has to be correct -

> I have no choice but killing you.

But I must make it a point here that this construction is very rare.

So let's summarise it -

> 3.(a) I have no choice but to kill you. (CORRECT) 
>   3.(b) I have no choice but killing you. (CORRECT but very rare) 
>   3.(c) I have no choice but kill you. (Doubtful. I would go as far as saying that it's incorrect, though I have some example sentences with similar constructions in CORPUS even more than the structure depicted in #3(b)]