# Is the sentence 'I have no choice not to do it' grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which of the two sentences is grammatically correct? I found the second sentence on line.

> 1. I have no choice but to do it.
> 2. I have no choice not to do it.

Comment: Where? Can you give us the source, please?

Comment: Related question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85410/i-have-no-choice-but-verbto-ing-or-none

Answer (score -1):

I'd say both of these sentences are correct, but the meanings are slightly different.

"I have no choice but to do it" means that doing it is mandatory - you have no choice, except to do the thing in question. For instance, it might be because your actions are mandated by a regulation - you aren't allowed to make a different choice.

"I have no choice not to do it" also means that doing the thing is mandatory, but the reason why is because you have no opportunity not to do the thing. This might be because it is unavoidably done in the course of other tasks you perform.