# Bare infinitive after except

Tags: infinitives, bare-infinitives

According to these two links [link1](https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive/) [link2](https://www.learn-english-today.com/lessons/lesson_contents/verbs/bare-infinitives.html), we should use bare infinitive after  “But, than, except”

But I have read the below sentence somewhere

> She had no choice except **to wait** for the next train.

So is this sentence wrong?

Answer (score 1):

*EXCEPT* takes a [matrix-licensed](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/85676/35026) complement: its complement is licensed by the verb in the main or *matrix* clause. In this case, the main verb is *HAVE*. *HAVE* allows a to-infinitival clause complement with a [deontic](https://www.lexico.com/definition/deontic) sense, as in:

> I had to wait for the next train

Since the complement of *EXCEPT* is licensed by *HAVE* and *HAVE* allows a to-infinitival complement, the sentence is grammatical.

Comment: Damn, I've been reading grammar texts for a while and you're still on a whole other level of jargon. Consider me impressed.